# PDO class use chain method

Tags: php, class, oop, methods, pdo

This is my "wrapper" class, over PDO (it is larger, this is the important part right now)

```
class DB
    {
        protected $pdo;
        protected $dsn;
        protected $username;
        protected $password;
        protected $driverOptions;
        protected $query;

        public function __construct($dsn, $username = '', $password = '', array $driverOptions = [])
        {
            $this->dsn = $dsn;
            $this->username = $username;
            $this->password = $password;
            $this->driver_options = $driverOptions;
        }

        public function connect()
        {
            $this->pdo = new PDO($this->dsn, $this->username, $this->password, (array)$this->driver_options);
            $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            return $this->pdo;
        }

        public function myQuery($sql)
        {
            $this->query = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
            $this->query->execute();
            return $this->query;
        }

        public function all()
        {
            $all = $this->query->fetchAll();
            $this->query->closeCursor();
            return $all;
        }
    }
```

This works perfectly(if a little change, in particular by adding type hinting), as such:

```
$class = new myPDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=***', 'login', 'pass');
$prepare = $class->connect()->prepare('SELECT * FROM test');
$prepare->execute();
$result = $prepare->fetch();
```

BUT I want to use it this way:

```
$pdo = new DB('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=***', 'login', 'pass');
$result = $pdo->connect()->myQuery('SELECT * FROM test')->all();
```

There was this error in my IDE:

> Method 'myQuery' not found in class PDO

Comment: I miss `extends PDO` (and more). Do you know how inheritance gets implemented? If not, dig into it!

Comment: @hek2mgl Probably i incorrectly wrote. I know what inheritance, and I do not want to do it. I want to make a "wrapper" over PDO.

Comment: Looks like you don't know it. How can you expect that the return value of `connect()` can have a method `myQuery`? You return a `PDO` in `connect()`, not a `DB`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class is acting as an abstraction over PDO, but you're leaking the actual PDO object whenever you write this:

```
return $this->pdo;
```

Consumers of this class should never need to know that that object exists, so you should not give it to them.

To get the chaining effect, all you have to do is give the caller back the object they already have, ready to make another call. In other words:

```
return $this;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what is necessary, and it works! Very handy with PHPDoc comments in the IDE.